# 'Enable Unread/Read on Compact Case Feed' feature impacting forceChatter:postCreated?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, chatter, feeditem, winter21

New feature: **Enable Unread/Read on Compact Case Feed** enabled in Support Settings from Winter '20
https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter20/release-notes/rn_cases_unread_read_feed_items.htm

Seems to impact **forceChatter:postCreated** event in lightning component, at least for email type feedItems.
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/forceChatter:postCreated/specification

Specifically when the feature is disabled, this event fires and we're able to access the FeedItem created and its actor's id (the user in my scenario) of who created it. (**FeedItem** - https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.chatterapi.meta/chatterapi/connect_responses_feed_item.htm) This has been in use for awhile.

When the feature is enabled and a user sends an email from the Chatter publisher on a Case, FeedItem and FeedItem.Actor.Id results in a lightning component pop up error saying 'actor' is undefined. I'm not able to access the ID either of the feed item anymore, however the email created from the standard chatter publisher sends and there is a feed item of the email within the UI as per usual. The 'Send' button after error occurs is grayed out until the page is refreshed.

Once the feature is disabled again, everything works.

Any ideas what could be causing this? Any more info on what that feature is doing and if it changes FeedItem or that event?